# GridSearchCV ignores train/test size

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I can't get GridSearchCV to respect my cross validation parameters. I'm doing the following:

```
folds = ShuffleSplit(n_splits = 5, train_size = 37, test_size=5, random_state=42)
grid = GridSearchCV(
                SVR(kernel='rbf'),
                cv=folds.split(X_scaled),
                param_grid={
                    'C': (.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000,1000000000),
                    'epsilon': .0001,
                    'gamma': (.00005, 0.0001, 0.0002)
                    }
                )

grid.fit(X_scaled, y_scaled)
```

The output of grid.fit lets me know that it is doing:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 21 candidates, totalling 84 fits
```

So it is respecting the number of folds but completely ignoring my parameter for the amount of data to use for train/test. I appear to be consistent with online code examples, but nothing makes it fit to anything other than 21 datapoints (half my sample).

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reported `21 candidates` are **not** datapoints; they are the 21 candidate **models** due to all possible parameter combinations requested in your `param_grid`, each of which corresponds to a candidate model:

- 7 candidate `C` values
- 1 candidate `epsilon`
- 3 candidate `gamma`

which makes `7*1*3 = 21` canditate models.